# SQL: Find all record from single table not like from 2 column

Tags: sql

I want fetch all the records from single Table except only when Column A has value X and Column B has value P. So for example

**Table:**

```
Value   Column A    Column B
1       X           P
2       X           Q
3       Y           P
4       Y           Q
5       Z           R
```

So I want to fetch all records except First record where  Column A has X and Column B has P value. Please help

Comment: I'd suggest first start reading [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) before accepting any of the answers which are correct

Comment: What do you mean by "except First record"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE columnA <> 'X' AND columnB <> 'P'
```

***Edited:***

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM yourtable t2 WHERE t1.Value = t2.Value AND t2.columnA = 'X' AND t2.columnB = 'P'
);

SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE NOT (columnA = 'X' AND columnB = 'P')
```

#### SqlFiddle Demo

Comment: But it will remove record with Value 2 or 3 also, Any Suggestion?

Comment: + for suggesting `NOT WHERE NOT (columnA = 'X' AND columnB = 'P')` option

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query:

```
Select * from Table_name 
Where not (Column_A = 'X' and Column_B = 'P')
```

Answer (score 1):

That will ckeck all records:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable
WHERE columnA <> 'X' AND columnB <> 'P'
```

If you want to apply the check only on the first record, you can try that:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable
WHERE value <> '1' AND columnA <> 'X' AND columnB <> 'P'
```

Comment: But it will remove record with Value 2 or 3 also, Any Suggestion?